# Magnolia CMS: renaming page creates 404 when using Urltrans module

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

[Urltrans module](https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Urltrans+Module) helps me to have internationalized URLs, but a single hierarchy.

---

Overall it works fine, except in that case:

1. Back in Magnolia CMS admin central, in the pages app, open a page
2. Let's say that I'm visualizing the page the page in German
3. Open the Page Properties Dialog
4. Change the (Localized) name
5. Save
6. `404 error message` in the "Page Preview" tab. The log says `2016-11-01 11:17:57,413 WARN  info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderingFilter    : Resource not found: [/<path>/<to>/<page>?mgnlPreview=false&mgnlChannel=desktop]`

---

This happens simply because the page that I am now trying to see in admin central is still the one with the "former name", hence the "former url path", hence a page that does not exist anymore.

I found this issue mentioned at [line 51 of UrltransSaveHandler.java](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/FORGE/repos/urltrans/browse/src/main/java/com/eqs/magnolia/urltrans/dialog/UrltransSaveHandler.java) (I think that's what I mean).

Any idea how I could prevent this from happening, for instance:

- simply programmatically close the current `Pages app`'s tab whenever the page name is changed?
- redirect the current tab to the view the page with the new URL path
- do NOT allow users to edit the Page Name from anywhere else than the `Page app's browser`
- another solution maybe?

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation

[`UrltransSaveHandler.java`](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/FORGE/repos/urltrans/browse/src/main/java/com/eqs/magnolia/urltrans/dialog/UrltransSaveHandler.java) is actually NOT used.

However, the [`SaveDialogAction.java`](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/users/apchelintcev/repos/ui/browse/magnolia-ui-admincentral/src/main/java/info/magnolia/ui/admincentral/dialog/action/SaveDialogAction.java?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmagnolia-ui-5.4.x) is configured in the `Action Definition` on the dialog.

That's the relevant dialog (if you have not overridden it): `admincentral#app:configuration:browser;/modules/standard-templating-kit/dialogs/generic/master/basePageProperties:treeview:`.

[`SaveDialogAction.java`](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/users/apchelintcev/repos/ui/browse/magnolia-ui-admincentral/src/main/java/info/magnolia/ui/admincentral/dialog/action/SaveDialogAction.java?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmagnolia-ui-5.4.x) calls `setNodeName(node, item)` at `line 81`.

This method is very similar to what was happening at `line 51` of [`UrltransSaveHandler.java`](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/FORGE/repos/urltrans/browse/src/main/java/com/eqs/magnolia/urltrans/dialog/UrltransSaveHandler.java): it does a "`if (node's "name" property has changed?){rename node itself}`".

---

#### Solution: in a nutshell

1. Create a new `Action Definition` that does exactly the same as the `SaveDialogAction` except this call to `setNodeName(node, item);` that only happens if the parent node is not of `NodeType` `mgnl:variant`
2. Assign this new `Class` to the `Commit` Action in the relevant dialog configuration

---

#### Action Definition class

```
package com.myproject.dialog;

import info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.dialog.action.SaveDialogActionDefinition;
import info.magnolia.ui.api.action.Action;

public class MyProjectUrltransSaveActionDefinition extends SaveDialogActionDefinition {

    public MyProjectUrltransSaveActionDefinition() {
        setImplementationClass((Class<? extends Action>) MyProjectUrltransSaveAction.class);
    }

}
```

#### Action class

```
package com.myproject.dialog;

import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.nodetype.NodeType;
import javax.jcr.Property;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.vaadin.data.Item;

import info.magnolia.cms.core.Path;
import info.magnolia.jcr.util.NodeUtil;
import info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.dialog.action.SaveDialogAction;
import info.magnolia.ui.api.action.ActionExecutionException;
import info.magnolia.ui.form.EditorCallback;
import info.magnolia.ui.form.EditorValidator;
import info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.integration.jcr.JcrNodeAdapter;
import info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.integration.jcr.ModelConstants;


public class MyProjectUrltransSaveAction<T extends MyProjectUrltransSaveActionDefinition> extends SaveDialogAction {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyProjectUrltransSaveAction.class);

    public MyProjectUrltransSaveAction(T definition, Item item, EditorValidator validator, EditorCallback callback) {
        super(definition, item, validator, callback);
    }

    public void execute() throws ActionExecutionException {
        if (validateForm()) {
            final JcrNodeAdapter item = (JcrNodeAdapter) this.item;
            try {
                final Node node = item.applyChanges();
                final Node parentNode = node.getParent();
                final String parentNodeType = parentNode.getPrimaryNodeType().getName();
                if(!parentNodeType.equals("mgnl:variant")){
                    setNodeName(node, item);
                }
                node.getSession().save();
            } catch (final RepositoryException e) {
                throw new ActionExecutionException(e);
            }
            callback.onSuccess(getDefinition().getName());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the node Name.
     * Node name is set to: <br>
     * the value of the property 'name' if it is present.
     */
    protected void setNodeName(Node node, JcrNodeAdapter item) throws RepositoryException {
        String propertyName = "name";
        if (node.hasProperty(propertyName) && !node.hasProperty(ModelConstants.JCR_NAME)) {
            Property property = node.getProperty(propertyName);
            String newNodeName = property.getString();
            if (!node.getName().equals(Path.getValidatedLabel(newNodeName))) {
                newNodeName = Path.getUniqueLabel(node.getSession(), node.getParent().getPath(), Path.getValidatedLabel(newNodeName));
                item.setNodeName(newNodeName);
                NodeUtil.renameNode(node, newNodeName);
            }
        }
    }

}
```